# Linux sed regex for currency

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

Hello I'm trying to remove from a textfile everything except currency values like:

```
$200,013,033.43
$2,000.32
$3000
```

Currently I have been using this command but only removes everything that is not a number so characters like "$,." are ignored

```
sed 's/[^0-9]*//g' myfile.txt >> output.txt
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: Is currency value always at start of line as shown?

Comment: It is not clear what you want your output to look like. "except currency values" could mean `$2,000.32` stays as it is, or becomes `2000.32`. A more realistic (but small) sample input file that includes non-currency lines would be helpful. As one person has already flagged, it is "unclear what you're asking".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
grep -o '$[0-9,.]\+' myfile.txt >> output.txt
```

outputs every occurance of set of digits, `,` and `.` which follows `$` symbol.

If you insist on `sed` (mostly GNU sed versions):

```
sed 's/[^$]*\($[0-9,.]\+\)/\1\n/
     T1
     P
     :1
     D' myfile.txt >> output.txt
```

for each line try to substitute set of any symbol(s) except `$` (`[^$]*`) and set of digits, `,` and `.` which follows `$` symbol by just last part + `n`ew line. If substitution didn't execute (there is not above pattern in line) pass to `1` point else print part of the line from start till first `\n`ew line symbol(i.e. required set). Next operation `D`elete part of the line from start till first `\n`ew line symbol if the one exists in the line  or full line and starts operations from the begining. So if the pattern empty (full line was deleted) script goes to next line else continue to operate with remaining part of the present line.

Or more simple (may be)

```
sed -n '/$[0-9,.]\+/{
                     s/[^$]*\($[0-9,.]\{1,\}\)[^$]*/\1\x0a/g
                     s/\n$//
                     p
                     }' myfile.txt >> output.txt
```

- `-n` suppress automatic printing of pattern space (prints the lines which is directed by `p`rint only)
- `/$[0-9,.]\+/ {` next commands applies just for lines which consist set of digits, `,` and `.` which follows `$` symbol
- `s/[^$]*\($[0-9,.]\{1,\}\)[^$]*/` the above set altogether with any symbols (except `$`) before and after it will be `s`ubstituted by
- `\1\x0a/` the founded set + `\n`ew line
- `g` for each occurence

The above operation may cause empty lines arise so `s/\n$//` has delete it.

Comment: It would be good to mention for posterity that this sed solution is specific to GNU sed.  Traditional sed (i.e. in OSX, FreeBSD, Solaris, etc) will not support things like `\n` in the replace string of a substitution. Also, for portability there should be a semicolon before the close curly brace.  +1 anyway though, because the question was after all tagged "linux", which as far as I'm aware only ever ships with GNU sed.

Comment: @ghoti I've make some changes to be more portable, so please try.

Comment: Both more portable and more readable.  Nicely done.  The only other thing I'd want to see would be an explanation of what this sed script does.  After all, we supply answers to help improve each other's skills and understanding.

Comment: @ghoti Brief explanation is added as required